# e-mail Forwarders in cpanel

Tags: cloud, cpanel

I have 2 servers, one is a cpanel server which is the email accounts main server. The other is a Microsoft server used under a subdomain (in a hybrid cloud environment) and it is used to provide AZ identities and some other emails account.

In the Microsoft server hoever, i got several exchange emails accounts (under various subdomains) and I need a way to tell cpanel that it must look for those emails addresses outside itself (on an external server)

How do I make that happen?

Any light on this dark matter would be apreciated.

I was thinking in using email forwarders but I dont know if that would really work.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please rephrase. You may give example which will help to understand.